# NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'RPA_tool' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['admin_tool/RPA_tool/(?P<Policy_Number>[^/]+)/$']

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to create a dynamic URL in my Django App to redirect from the Search Page to RPA_Tool/<Policy_Number>

When I attempt to load the search page, I receive the error
Reverse for 'RPA_tool' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['admin_tool/RPA_tool/(?P<Policy_Number>[^/]+)/$']

I've tried swapping it to use datadisplay.Policy_ID, and that has successfully redirected to Policy_ID. However, when I change the hyperlink to datadisplay.Policy_Number, I receive the error.

here is the HTML:

```
  <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="searchTable()" placeholder="Search for Policy..">
  <table class = "table">

      <tr class="header">
        <th>Policy ID</th>
        <th>Policy Numbers</th>
      </tr>
    

    <tbody id="myTable">
    {% for datadisplay in Policies %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{datadisplay.Policy_ID}}</td>
        <td>{{datadisplay.Policy_Number}}</td>
        <td> <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{% url 'RPA_tool' datadisplay.Policy_Number %}"> Update </a> </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Views.py:

```
def searchPolicies(request):
    Policies = getPolicyNumbers()
    myfilter = PoliciesFilter()
    context = {'myfilter': myfilter}
    return render(request, 'admin_tool/search.html', {'Policies':Policies, 'myfilter': myfilter})

def RPA_tool(request): 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RPA_tool_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            policyNumber = form.cleaned_data.get('Policy_Number')
            messages.success(request, f'{policyNumber} Saved')
            editRPADetails(form)
            return redirect('/admin_tool/')
    else:

        form = RPA_tool_form(initial={'Policy_Number':'Test'})
    return render(request, 'admin_tool/RPA_tool.html', {'form':form})
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
# from users import views as user_views


urlpatterns = [
    # path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='UW-home'),
    path('admin_tool/', views.admin_tool, name ='admin_tool'),
    path('RPA_tool/<str:Policy_Number>/', views.RPA_tool, name ='RPA_tool'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='Admin_Tool about'),
    path('search/', views.searchPolicies, name='searchPolicies')
]
```

Comment: If `datadisplay.Policy_ID` works but `datadisplay.Policy_Number` doesn't then either `Policy_Number` is a typo, or perhaps you have some policies in the database where the `Policy_Number` is not set.

Comment: I've double checked for a typo or for a missing Policy_Number, but it looks like neither of them are the issue. Would really appreciate any other suggestions you might have

Comment: To debug, you could wrap the `{% url %}` tag in an if statement, so that you only display the link when the policy number is set: `{% if datadisplay.Policy_Number %}<a ...>Update </a> </td>{% else %}{{ datadisplay.Policy_Number }}{% endif %}`

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Some Policy_Numbers were set to '' rather than Null, which broke the URL. Really appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the field 'Policy_Number' is empty
In your database you got models where field Policy_Number is empty.
You can check it in django admin